# Dax calculate a metric for another day in the calendar table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a date column and a money column:

```
Thedate CashCollected
2039-12-28  100
2039-12-27  200
2039-12-26  300
2039-12-25  400
2039-12-24  500
2039-12-23  600
2039-12-22  700
2039-12-21  800
```

and then I have the date table with the date and the previous working day calculated following some specific conditions:

```
TheDate  PrevItWorkDay
2039-12-28  2039-12-27
2039-12-27  2039-12-23
2039-12-26  2039-12-23
2039-12-25  2039-12-23
2039-12-24  2039-12-23
2039-12-23  2039-12-22
2039-12-22  2039-12-21
2039-12-21  2039-12-20
```

I would like to calculate in DAX a measure which gives me the sum of cash collected for the previous working day in the date table:

```
TheDate  PrevItWorkDay
2039-12-28  200
2039-12-27  600
2039-12-26  600
2039-12-25  600
2039-12-24  600
2039-12-23  700
2039-12-22  800
2039-12-21
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PrevWorkingDaySum = 
CALCULATE( 
   SUM(TransactionTable[CashCollected]) ,  
   TransactionTable[Thedate]= SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[PrevItWorkDay])
)
```

[image]

Comment: your precise version didnt work but this slightly different version did:

   CALCULATE( 
      [CashCollected] ,  -- This is a measure
      DateTable[Thedate]= SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[PrevItWorkDay])
   )